# EBS IOPS First Use Penalty with snapshot volumes

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

When creating a Provisioned IOPS EBS volume (or any EBS volumes for that matter) from a snapshot, are the "First Use Penalty” effects avoided?

Are they only partially avoided (for the blocks that are written) from the snapshot, or are they completely avoided?

If the former, is there a way to pre-warm only the blocks that are not written from the snapshot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes same applies to volumes created from the snapshot.
The EBS will get attached to the instance and mounted but it will be still pulling data from S3.

For me it was a problem and I did something like this before spinning the app to the fullest to see if all data was copied from S3 snapshot:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdX of=/dev/null bs=10M
```

By the time this command is done you can be sure all the data has been copied.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I did just a little too-little searching before asking this question....

There was a [question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904678/how-to-warm-up-ec2-ebs-storage):

Which referenced the [an AWS forum entry](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=198413#198413) that confirms Danila's answer: